# interpretation of a singular integral

Tags: harmonic-analysis, integration

There is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787844/principal-value-integral-of-complex-exponential) on MSE about a principal value integral in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1267453933). It has not received much attention even with a bounty, and since it concerns a published paper, I believe this is a better forum for the topic.

The integral in question is the third of this remark
[image: remark 1]

and it is based on this lemma
[image: lemma 1]

I believe there is a problem with the integral as I pointed out in my answer on MSE. My question is the following: Is there a problem with the integral, or is there an interpretation that makes it valid, possibly some finite part interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely wrong. The two first integrals are defined as principal values, allowing to cancel the sine parts, and conclude with the lemma (actually, [as OP already knows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820153/412436), the lemma itself do not need to be expressed as principal value). But for the third one, it is not even clear how a principal value could be defined. Since one needs to bound away both $t$ and $s$ from zero, I would go for integrating over $D_\epsilon = \left(\mathbb{R}^p \setminus (\epsilon B_p \cup \epsilon^{- 1}B_p^{c}) \right) \times \left(\mathbb{R}^q \setminus (\epsilon B_q \cup \epsilon^{- 1}B_q^{c}) \right)$, where $B_p$ and $B_q$ are the appropriate unit balls. But now set $Y = 0$, so that for $X \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\int_{D_\epsilon}
\frac{1 - \exp(\mathrm{i}\left<t,X\right>)}
     {\Vert t \Vert^{p+1} \Vert s \Vert^{q+1}} \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}s =
\int_{\mathbb{R}^p \setminus (\epsilon B_p \cup \epsilon^{- 1}B_p^{c})}
\frac{1}{\Vert s \Vert^{q+1}}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^p \setminus (\epsilon B_p \cup \epsilon^{- 1}B_p^{c})}
\frac{1 - \cos(\left<t,X\right>)}
     {\Vert t \Vert^{p+1}} \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}s.$$

But then by virtue of the lemma, with $X \neq 0$, the inner integral (over $t$) is bounded away from zero for $\epsilon$ small enough, and thus the above quantity diverges. This is far from being equal to zero, as the third equality would imply.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "finite part interpretation" is what makes these formulas valid, including the third one: it amounts to computing the distributional Fourier transform of the "pseudo-function" (and tempered distribution) Pf$|x|^{-n-1}$ (in $\mathbb R^n$), which is proportional to $|\xi|$, with the constant given. (The finite part of $\int\int |s|^{-p-1}|t|^{-q-1}\ ds\ dt$ vanishes, obviously, so that the third "integral", while diverging, has a finite part which is exactly minus the product of Fourier transforms of two such pseudo-functions).

I agree with Hugo Raguet that lemma 1 wrongly calls upon a principal value, since the integrand is integrable.

Fourier transforms of pseudo-functions Pf$|x|^\alpha$, $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, may be found e.g. in Schwartz's *Théorie des distributions*, formula (VII, 7; 13) and (VII, 7; 14), p. 257 and 258 in my copy of 1973.